# Loop using variable that changes every loop-calculation with certain step-size

Tags: loops, fortran

I am using a loop that adds a value (`step`) to `dist`. After adding `step` to `dist` I would like to use it in the following calculation which provides the value `c`. Both, `dist` and `c`, should then be listed in two columns next to each other in an output file.

If I use the code below it works at least to list the values for `dist` in the output file.

```
dist=0
  do while (dist < rim)
   dist=dist+step
   c=0.5*(cl-cr)*erfc((dist)/(2*sqrt(t*d)))+cr
   write(1,'(1f20.0)')dist*1E+06
  enddo
```

If I replace the write command by the one below it will not list two nice columns but somehow mix both.

```
  write(1,'(1f20.0,1f15.5)')dist*1E+06,c
```

Is this a problem related to the positioning of the writing command in the loop or is it related to the format it is told to write the values?

Comment: *"but somehow mix both."* How somehow? Please show an example end explain why is it wrong and how should it look like instead. Is your question about a loop or about formatting?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a space between them and re-check:

```
write(*,'(F20.0,1X,F15.5)') dist*1E+06, c
```

Also consider the accuracy with which you are writing the results to the file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I hope you mean `1X` instead of just `X` @VladimirF .

Comment: Yes, it is fine now.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I did add a space between now, but that didn't help. I think the routine calculates more than one "`c`"-value.

            `dist(um)                   c
                  2.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047
                  0.         0.24047`

Comment: I now found the error. I wrote allocate `c(n)` in the beginning of the code, whereas `n` referred to a certain number that was already given by another input-file. I could solve the problem by replacing `n` by `1`. Thank you for your thoughts